# Read lines of file over HTTP on demand

Tags: python, iterator, python-requests, lazy-loading, urllib

What I need to do is to read a file over HTTP in chunks (iterate over lines to be specific). I want to ***not*** read the entire file (or a large part of it) and then split it into lines, but rather read a small (<=8kB) chunk and then split this into lines. When all the lines in chunk are consumed, then receive the next chunk.

I have tried the following:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
  yield from f
```

Which didn't work. In Wireshark I see that about 140kB of total ~220kB are received just by calling `urlopen(url)`.

The next thing I tried was to use `requests`:

```
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as req:
  yield from req.iter_lines()
```

Which also reads about 140kB just by calling `get(url, stream=True)`. According to the [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) this should not happen. Other than that, I did not find any information about this behavior or how to control it. I'm using Requests 2.21.0, CPython 3.7.3, on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests) and [docs 2](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests) (and given that the source is actually working in chunks) I think you should use `iter_content`, which accepts the chunk_size parameter which you have to set to None:

```
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as req:
    yield from req.iter_content(chunk_size=None)
```

I haven't tried, but is seems that somewhere in you code something accesses `req.content` before `iter_lines`, therefore loading the entire payload.

edit_ added example

Comment: I am aware of `iter_content` and have tried that as well. As I mentioned in the question, the data is loaded before I even call any methods on the `req` object. My code most definitely does not access `req.content` before calling `iter_lines` or anything else. I tested this by calling `requests.get` alone, without anything else. And BTW the two links in your post are the same.